# The web API for Httpget request which read the data from the database

Tags: asp.net, database, api, datamodel, controllercontext

public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> ReadClassData()
{

```
            var data = await _classdata.ReadClassData.TolistAsync();

            var classData = data.Select(c => new tblclass
            {
                classId = c.classId,
                className = c.className,
                Quantity = c.QUANTITY
            }).ToList();

            return classData()!;
        
        
    }
```

i am trying to solve but i am not getting error in this code

Answer (score 0):

You are using repository right?
Dont use repository much but this code is in using ef context:

```
var data = _context.Classes.Select(c=>new tblclass{
classId = c.classId,
className = c.className,
Quantity = c.QUANTITY}).ToList();return data;
```

this code only get needed properties for you, you dont need to get all data from sql, if you need to get 1000 rows with all column, it slower than only get property you need